# dcast and aggregate to length in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am coming from R background so struggling to achieve what I can easily achieve in R, I have following pandas dataframe.

```
ID   credit_active    credit_currency      credit_type
1    Active           Dollars              Home
1    Closed           Dollars              Home
1    Active           Euro                 Home
2    Active           Dollars              Home
2    Closed           Dollars              Home
2    Active           Euro                 Home
```

I want data in following format

```
ID     Active    Closed     Dollars     Euro     Home
1      2         1          2           1        3
2      2         1          2           1        3
```

I can achieve this in R with simple command as follows,

```
dcast(melt(setDT(bureau), id.var = 'ID'), ID ~ value)
```

How can I do the same thing pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.melt('ID').groupby(['ID', 'value']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Another solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.melt('ID').pivot_table(index='ID', columns='value', aggfunc='size')
```

Or with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('ID')
df = pd.crosstab(df1['ID'], df1['value'])
```

---

```
print (df)
value  Active  Closed  Dollars  Euro  Home
ID                                        
1           2       1        2     1     3
2           2       1        2     1     3
```

Comment: Sorry,a basic question though, how can we change first column name to ID?

Comment: When I try to change the datatype of `ID` to `object` `df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(object)` It gives me an error.

Comment: I was able to do it with `reset_index`. Thanks